# hibernate Transactional and sql query vs criteria query

Tags: java, hibernate

I met a problem when doing query in @Transitional method

Below is the code:

```
@Test
@Rollback
@Transactional
public void testFindOneReportOrderWithTwoItemWithSameFnsku() throws Exception
{
    //Prepare the order
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    ReportOrder order = new ReportOrder();
    order.setId(111111);
    order.setCustomerId("test customer");

    session.persist(order);
    // session.flush();

    System.out.println("Start ====================");
    System.out.println("criteria search:");
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    System.out.println(session.createCriteria(ReportOrder.class).list());    


    System.out.println("sql query:");
    System.out.println(session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Orders").list());


    System.out.println("End ==========================");
}
```

The test is:

1. If I comment line 13 "session.flush", and line 17,18 "criteria search"
   then I will get no result in sql query
2. If I comment line 13 only
   then I will get all results in both criteria search and sql search
3. If I not comment line 13
   then I will get result from sql search.

My problem is:

1. Why I can get sql search result after execute criteria search?
2. Why I cannot get sql result after sesson.persist()?

Answer (score 0):

When using the default flush mode, Hibernate sessions are flushed before running Criteria based queries.  Hibernate sessions are *not* flushed before running the SQL based query.

Here is some more information on how Hibernate works with native SQL queries: http://vladmihalcea.com/the-dark-side-of-hibernate-auto-flush/

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered issues related to flushing of pending DB updates. Hibernate optimizes by not flushing changes to the DB until it needs to. When you execute a query that hibernate understands, it flushes as necessary. The problem is that hibernate doesn't look at the SQL that you are executing and figure out which entities the query depends on, so it flushes nothing. When you use SQL, you should be using methods such as `addSynchronizedEntityClass` or `addSynchronizedEntityName` to tell hibernate which entities are touched by the SQL query.

Try something like:

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Orders").addSynchronizedEntityClass(ReportOrder.class).list()
```